# Object is possibly 'undefined' When trying to get width of html element using JQUERY in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use JSPDF to convert a table into PDF with multiple pages. So as part of that I am  trying to get width and height of my html

```
var HTML_Width = $("#pdfTable").width();
var HTML_Height = $("#pdfTable").height();
var top_left_margin = 15;
var PDF_Width:number = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
```

But in above snippet HTML_width shows Object is possible undefined.

[image]

How to resolve that

Answer (score 2):

If there is no element with the `id` `pdfTable`, jQuery's `$()` will return an empty jQuery object, and calls to `width` and `height` on that empty object will return `undefined`. As a result, their return type is `number | undefined`.

If you **know** (or rather, *expect*) that the element will exist, you can document that in the code and reassure TypeScript by throwing an error if that expectation is not met, like this:

```
var HTML_Width = $("#pdfTable").width();
var HTML_Height = $("#pdfTable").height();
if (typeof HTML_Width === "undefined" || typeof HTML_Height === "undefined") {
    throw new Error(`Expected element with id="pdfTable"`);
}
var top_left_margin = 15;
var PDF_Width:number = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
```

You can also use a [non-nullish assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (a postfix `!`), but like all type assertions, it's best to avoid it in favor of guards like the above where possible. But for completeness:

```
// I don't recommend this
var HTML_Width = $("#pdfTable").width()!;
//                                     ^
var HTML_Height = $("#pdfTable").height()!;
//                                       ^
var top_left_margin = 15;
var PDF_Width:number = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
```